# Create SQL table with variable name?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Im making a to-do list app that allows users to create multiple checklists. In each checklist users can add an item to that particular checklist.

Im using SQLite to save the checklists. I need to be able to create a new table when the user creates a checklist. the name of the new table will be the string they entered when creating the checklist.

How can I do this?

Comment: Don't. Create two tables: `checklists` and `items`. In the `items` table, create a foreign key `checklist_id`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain a bit more or give an example?

Comment: Create an **checklist_id** field in `items` which relates to the **id** field in `checklists`, so you can join them.